# How to use Cocoa's Responder Chain when Application is Minimized

Tags: cocoa, action, target, chain

I'm using the responder chain (sendAction:to:from:) to communicate from sub-views up to the document. The problem is when the window is minimized, if there are any actions still occurring, they fail because the responder chain is broken. I can't make the window a key window since it's minimized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out how to do this using NSResponder:

```
- (BOOL)tryToPerform:(SEL)anAction with:(id)anObject
```

If the receiver responds to anAction, it invokes the method with anObject as the argument and returns YES. If the receiver doesn’t respond, it sends this message to its next responder with the same selector and object.